# R Shiny: How to color margin of title panel?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to color the title panel of my app, including the margins.
So far I am able to color the panel.
So basically I want all margins of the title panel to be in the color coral.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel(h1("Hello Shiny!",style={'background-color:coral;'})
             )
  ,

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                  label = "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    x    <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
         xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
         main = "Histogram of waiting times")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at your page with a browser's developper tools (e.g. `ctrl+shift+i` in chrome), you'll see your title panel is in a big `container-fluid` div with 15px padding left and right.

You cannot color the padding of that page only around the title.

However, you can take the title out of the fluid page so that it is not impacted by the padding. This means your title will be flush with the left border of your page. You may want to introduce some left padding, for example 15px.

```r
ui <- tagList(
   titlePanel(h1("Hello Shiny!",
              style='background-color:coral;
                     padding-left: 15px')), 
   fluidPage( 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                        label = "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        mainPanel(
            plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
        )
    )
))
```

[image]

Alternatively, a pure CSS solution is to negate the fluid page margin and replace it by padding from the title, effectively extending the title box by 15px left and right to compensate for the page padding.

```r
ui <- fluidPage(  

  titlePanel(h1("Hello Shiny!",
                style={'background-color:coral;
                        margin-left: -15px;
                        margin-right: -15px;
                        padding-left: 15px;'})
  ),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                  label = "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
    )
  )
)
```

Same result with different underlying page structures:

- Option 1 puts the title before the main app's page (which has the 15px padding).
- Option 2 keeps the title inside the main page but makes it bleed it out left and right by 15px (the size of the page padding).

Now this makes for some ugly code. You also break the tab title by using an `h1` tag in the `titlePanel`.

Better to write your own titlePanel.

The original code is:

```r
function (title, windowTitle = title) 
{
    tagList(tags$head(tags$title(windowTitle)), h2(title))
}
```

Replace with:

```r
myTitlePanel <- function (title, windowTitle = title, color = "coral") {
    css <- paste(paste0("background-color:", color),
                 "padding-left: 15px",
                 "margin-left: -15px",
                 "margin-right: -15px",
                 sep = ";")
    tagList(tags$head(tags$title(windowTitle)), 
            h1(title, style = css))
}
```

Then your UI becomes:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(

  myTitlePanel("Hello Shiny!", color = "coral"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                  label = "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
    )
  )
)
```

Much cleaner and making it easy to change background color.